# How do I remove an app purchased in the past from the macOS App Store?

Tags: mac, mac-appstore

I have a new clean installation of macOS Catalina on my MacBook Pro.

When I open the macOS App Store and look at my account, I can see a list of all the apps I ever purchases (or downloaded for free).  It shows me "cloud-with-downarrow" icon for re-downloading the app, and there's a "..." icon that shows a pop-up menu with the option to "Hide purchase ..."

QUESTION: Is there a way to remove/delete the app "permanently" with no record whatsoever?  There are plenty of apps in that list that I will never use again, and it's just clutter for it to remain here.